# Tizen native companion Application. Any good sources to follow to start the development?

Tags: tizen-native-app, nativeapplication, samsung-gear-s2, samsung-gear

i am trying to build an native companion app for gear s2. I was trying to start build the project but i am stuck at the point that i dunno how to set up the Samsung Accessory Protocol. I have read this 
[native-companion/setup](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/native-companion/setup-sdk) but it seems to be unclear for me to follow. Could anyone give me tutorials or some resources to read on how to set up the communication between watch and Android app (step by step would be perfect) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the **Samsung Accessory SDK** programming guide. You can get it from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory/guide). You need to install Samsung Gear Manager on your Android phone in order to pair your Samsung Gear.

Update:

To use **SAP** in your gear app follow [this](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/native-companion/use-sap).

**API** Reference for Tizen Wearable Native is [here](http://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/native_sap/group__SAMSUNG__ACCESSORY__PROTOCOL.html).

Download the Accessory SDK **sample app** from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory).

From Tizen IDE you can also get help.

Go to *Tizen IDE> Help > Dynamic Help >Samsung Extension for Wearable Native > Programming Guide*

Comment: Hi i think this is useful for Android site and i am trying to implement the SAP in the Gear S2 (native with Tizen). Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Check now and let me know.

Comment: I have followed this but this is kinda complicated to me. Is there any nice tutorial to SAP implementation which lead through me step by step? Thanks